# How to print curret user's address

Tags: javascript, php, location, maps

First of all, please apologize my English.

Hi! I need to print with PHP the current user´s address, i have this small script:

```
<?
  function getaddress($lat,$lng)
  {
     $url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.trim($lat).','.trim($lng).'&sensor=false';
     $json = @file_get_contents($url);
     $data=json_decode($json);
     $status = $data->status;
     if($status=="OK")
     {
       return $data->results[0]->formatted_address;
     }
     else
     {
       return false;
     }
  }
?>

<?php
  $lat= 21.884766199999998; //latitude
  $lng= -102.2996459; //longitude
  $address= getaddress($lat,$lng);
  if($address)
  {
    echo $address;
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Not found";
  }
?>
```

of course it works, but I don't know how to change the $lat and $long variables to the current users location.

In few words; how I can pass the current user lat and long location to the PHP variables to let this script works?

Comment: PHP doesn't provide this functionality by default, you will need to use some sort of external API to get the information.

Comment: Thanks for yout answer, I'm starting searching in Google Maps Api.

Comment: no-one can guarantee the correct address or lat-lang if user have some proxy setting or firewall to spoof IP-address

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo">Click the button to get your coordinates:</p>
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
<script>
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }
function showPosition(position)
  {
  x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;    
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is an javascript based search. you can try it in html browser and pass the lat long to the php scripts.

if it helps you its ok or you can tell , i have other ways too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get this using JavaScript or other google api. Which you can place lat & lang in an separate hidden field and then assign to your php variables from that hidden fields.

Here is an example script to get this using html 5 and java-script

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
}
</script>
```

This is another script using google Geo-location API

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Geolocation</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      // Note: This example requires that you consent to location sharing when
      // prompted by your browser. If you see the error "The Geolocation service
      // failed.", it means you probably did not give permission for the browser to
      // locate you.
      var map, infoWindow;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 6
        });
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

        // Try HTML5 geolocation.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };

            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
            infoWindow.open(map);
            map.setCenter(pos);
          }, function() {
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
          });
        } else {
          // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
          handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }
      }

      function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                              'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                              'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
        infoWindow.open(map);
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```